# C++ Replace a character/characters in a string

Tags: c++, string, char, character, digits

I have a task which I can't find a solution to complete.

From the input there is a number 'n' which contains how many strings there are going to be typed later. Then there is a string, going in one by one. It is considered as a password. The string(password) needs to contain a low latin character, upper latin character and a number.

If the string contains only lowercase characters, some of them need to be replaced with an uppercase and a number, for example: aaaaaa -> Aaaaa1

The length of the string needs to remain the same.

If the entered string meets the conditions above, it should be printed out as it was entered.

Here's the code I wrote in C++...
I am missing the method of replacing the needed characters.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string s;
    int br1=0, br2=0, br3=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> s;
        for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++)
        {
            if(s[j]>='a' && s[j]<='z')
                br1++;
            else if(s[j]>='A' && s[j]<='Z')
                br2++;
            else if(s[j]>='0' && s[j]<='9')
                br3++;
        }
        if(br1 && br2 && br3)
            cout<<s;
        //else

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please provide input (better hardcoded) and output and expected output of your code

Comment: INPUT: 

2
abcDCE
htQw27

OUTPUT: 
abcD4E
htQw27

The 'abcD4E' output can be also written as '1bcD4E' 'a1cD4E' 'ab1DCE', you get the point.

Comment: Just use `s[j] = 'A'` wherever your find it appropriate. That's the method of replacing chars in C++.

Comment: Does it matter which character gets changed if it doesn't meet the requirement?

Comment: @ViktorIlievski You want to replace only if all the character are small?

Comment: First of all I suggest you learn about the [standard character classification functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification). Then to replace a single character [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is nice. Or you can use [`std::string::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace).

Comment: @YuriyF It doesn't matter which character needs to be replaced, the conditions must be met before the output: 1number, 1lowercase, 1uppercase

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude http://prntscr.com/kwq0b0 Here's a link of the problem. The output can differ, 'abcD4E' is just an example. It can accept the solution as '1bcDCE' and so on.

Comment: For readability, consider replacing your character range checks such as " s[j]>='a' && s[j]<='z' " with a readable function, perhaps is_lowerCase(char k),  is_upperCase(char K), and is_digit(char digit), and then you might look for already existing functions like std::isupper(int), std::islower(int), etc.